# Trigger on Phone Number - Not Working

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

My Requirement is to, whenever there is Phone Number entered in case Object, then in that case, if User enters any Special Characters, then it should ignore the Special Characters and display only the Digits.

I wrote a Trigger on it. Seems to be Correct. But, not working while I am testing.Please someone test in your Org and let me know, where I did mistake.

```
trigger PhNumValidation on Case (before insert,before update) {
    list<case> clist=new list<case>();
    for(Case c:Trigger.new){
      if (c.Phone_Number__c != null ) {
           string phone =c.Phone_Number__c;
          string newph=phone.replaceAll('\\D','');
          system.debug('Ph: '+newph);
        }   
          
           
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. I suggest you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357674/edit) your post and include a copy of your unit test class for the community to assist further.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for including code, but that is not enough information. Please take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the Help Center - especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it states, _'...a question post should include 1) A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help). plus ... 3) and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.'_ Please edit your question to add info.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger doesn't do anything. It creates a variable and then takes no action on it:

```
      if (c.Phone_Number__c != null ) {
           string phone =c.Phone_Number__c;
          string newph=phone.replaceAll('\\D','');
          system.debug('Ph: '+newph);
        }
```

You would need to write an assignment to `c.Phone_Number__c` to persist the data you've created.